# Select2, how get selected values and add new values

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, edit

Ok, I`m use Select2. i do "create method" with select2, its work greate, ok , how can i do "edit method"?? in EditMethod i wanna see in List already selected values and add new, if i want. 
Here code For createMethod, Im really new in it, please Help!

```
   public ActionResult Edit(int id = 0)
    {
       NIRs nir = db.NIRs.Find(id);
        if (nir == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        ViewBag.IFile = new MultiSelectList(db.IFile, "Id", "NazvanieFaila");
        return View(nir);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Edit(NIRs nir, int[] selectedFiles)
    {

        NIRs newNIR = db.NIRs.Find(nir.Id);
        newNIR.Name = nir.Name;
        if (selectedFiles != null)
        {
            foreach (var FileId in selectedFiles)
            {
                IFile files = db.IFile.Find(FileId);
                nir.IFile.Add(files);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            nir.IFile.Clear();
        }

            db.Entry(newNIR).State = EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("NirList");
    }
```

And ViewCode :

```
    @using NIR.Models
@model NIR.Models.NIRs

<link href="~/Content/select2.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="~/Scripts/select2.js"></script>

<div align="center">
    @using (Html.BeginForm())
    {
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

        <h2>Edit</h2>
        <legend>
            <div style="overflow-x: auto; width: auto;">
                <table align="center" class="TFtable">
                       <tr>
                        <td>
                            <div class="editor-label">
                                Name:
                            </div>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <div class="editor-field">
                                @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Name)
                            </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                     <tr>
                        <td>
                            <div class="editor-label">
                                Files:
                            </div>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <div class="editor-field">
                                @Html.ListBox("IFile")
                            </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
        </legend>
        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Save Changes" />
        </p>

    }

    @section Scripts {
        @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
    }
</div>


<script type="text/javascript">

        $("#IFile").select2(
            {
                placeholder: "Choose files",
                width: 300
            });
    </script>
```

Comment: You need to post the model your bind to. It should have a property `public int[] SelectedFiles { get; set; }` or similar and use `@Html.ListBoxFor(m => m.SelectedFiles, (SelectList)ViewBag.IFile). If `SelectedFiles` contains an array of values matching the values of the options, then they will be selected when the view is generated.

Comment: ok, i`m trying do, that u say. I use databasefirst and just insert in model  `public int[] selectedFiles { get; set; }` and next change ActionResult Edit
            `if (nir.selectedFiles != null)
            {
                foreach (var FileId in nir.selectedFiles)
                {
                    IFile files = db.IFile.Find(FileId);
                    nir.IFile.Add(files);
                }
            }`
and change view
`@Html.ListBoxFor(m => m.selectedFiles, (MultiSelectList)ViewBag.IFile)`, but i just see listbox with items, whats wrong?

Comment: Whats the parameter `int[] selectedFiles` in you POST method? You don't have any controls named `selectedFiles` so that will always be null. I cant understand your last comment because of the formatting - best to edit you question with the new code you tried. But if `IFile` table contains `Id`'s 1 to 10 and you set the value of `SelectedFiles = new int[] { 2,4 };` in the GET method then the 2nd and 4th options will be selected when the view is displayed

Comment: http://jsbin.com/tuwulepudi/2/edit?html,console  Please, look at it, and may be you understand

Comment: You have not set the value of `SelectedFiles` in the GET method so nothing will be selected when the view is first displayed (that's how model binding works - its binds to the value of your property!)

Comment: Can prescribe exemplary of this code ?
I understand you a little bit , but I still can not figure out how to do what is necessary to..

Comment: Just start by hard coding the value of `SelectedFiles` in the GET method as I indicated above to see that it works - nir.SelectedFiles = new int[] { 2,4 }; return View(nir);` (obviously the values need to match some Id's of the options)

Comment: ok, thats work, but they just selected in the list , but as I cram it in Select2?

Comment: http://blog.developer.idv.tw/2014/08/select2mvc.html I think this blog help me))

Comment: Stephen, Thanks a lot of much))))